# What is the advantage of installing Chrome Apps for Google Docs, Sheet etc

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

Google has released updated versions for its Docs, Sheet Apps in the Chrome Webstore like:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs/aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

My question is what is the difference since they still don't work offline?

Answer (score 1):

There's little difference between "installing" these applications in Chrome, and adding them as bookmarks. You do get a nice view of them from the "blank tab" screen, though.

Some applications also add buttons to Chrome's interface. That does not seem to be the case with any of the Google Apps Chrome Apps, but they may be added in the future.

Comment: What's that little difference other than a home screen icon?

Comment: For those apps you mentioned, it seems there's no difference. But Google might decide to add features to the apps later on, and having them installed will give you those updates.